# How catch error message from server nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, frontend, backend

Sup guys! This is the code on server side when something goes wrong:

`return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Email already used!'});`

And this is my frontend code that I try to catch the error message:

```
return async dispacth => {
        try {

            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3333/account/signin', userData);

            localStorage.setItem('JWT_TOKEN', res.data.token);

            dispacth({
                type: AUTH_SIGN_IN,
                token: res.data.token
            });

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            console.error('error', err);

            dispacth({
                type: AUTH_ERROR,
                errorMessage: err.message
            });
        }
    }
```

But this is what I got on browser's console:

[image]

Comment: Try `err.response.body.error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `res.status(400).send('Email already used!');`

You could do:

```
console.log(error.response.data.message);
```

For the error message being sent as a JSON object like `res.status(400).send({ error: 'Email already used!'});`

You could do:

```
console.log(error.response.data.error);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log(err.response)` instead of `console.log(err.message)`.

I'm new to Node and Axios, but using "err.response" after catching "err" fixed a very similar issue I had.